# Migration from postgres 9.4 to postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.4, upgrade, postgresql-9.6

I did the migration from PostgreSQL 9.4 to version 9.6, but now the stream replication is not working, it stopped replicating.

Script followed:

1. installation of postgres 9.6 on the three servers (master, slave1 and slave2).
2. running pg_upgrade on the three servers

The message that appears in the slaves server database log is as follows:

> 2017-07-13 19:01:46 -03 [25188]: [1-1] user =, db =, client =, appname
> = FATAL: databa System identifier differs between the primary and standby
>
> 2017-07-13 19:01:46 -03 [25188]: [2-1] user =, db =, client =,
> appname = DETAIL: The p Rimary's identifier is 6442320581826004577, the standby's identifier is 64423219
> 34563538204.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I think you are supposed **not** to run pg_upgrade in the slaves. Read [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html) procedures again.

Comment: *"running pg_upgrade on the three servers"*. How exactly was `pg_upgrade` run? With what parameters (in each installation)? Were the original instances stopped? In what order were the steps of the whole procedure taken?

Comment: If you want to go forward, without waiting for a complete answer to the issue - and assuming that your master has been upgraded and works properly in 9.6 - you can always setup replication (using 9.6) to the slaves from scratch (scrapping or not the existing malfunctioning setups).